# how to "spread" a list-column?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
mydf <- data_frame(regular_col = c(1,2),
                   normal_col = c('a','b'),
                   weird_col = list(list('hakuna', 'matata'),
                                 list('squash', 'banana')))

> mydf
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  regular_col normal_col weird_col 
        <dbl> <chr>      <list>    
1           1 a          <list [2]>
2           2 b          <list [2]>
```

I would like to extract the elements of `weird_col` (programmatically, the number of elements may change) so that each element is placed on a different column. That is, I expect the following output

```
> data_frame(regular_col = c(1,2),
+           normal_col = c('a','b'),
+           weirdo_one = c('hakuna', 'squash'),
+           weirdo_two = c('matata', 'banana'))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  regular_col normal_col weirdo_one weirdo_two
        <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1           1 a          hakuna     matata
2           2 b          squash     banana
```

However, I am unable to do so in simple terms. For instance, using the classic `unnest` fails here, as it expands the dataframe instead of placing each element of the list in a different column.

```
> mydf %>% unnest(weird_col)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  regular_col normal_col weird_col
        <dbl> <chr>      <list>   
1           1 a          <chr [1]>
2           1 a          <chr [1]>
3           2 b          <chr [1]>
4           2 b          <chr [1]>
```

Is there any solution in the `tidyverse` for that?

Comment: you know Swahili?

Comment: I know the Lion King haha :)

Comment: how deeply nested is the weird col? 2 levels or more?

Comment: `mydf%>%group_by(regular_col)%>%mutate(weird_col = invoke(paste,weird_col,collapse=","))%>%separate(weird_col,c("col1","col2"))`

Comment: @Onyambu pretty cool as well. what is the purpose of `invoke` here?

Comment: invoke is exactly the same as `do.call`

Comment: @Onyambu asante sana :D

Comment: `invoke` is similar to `do.call` (and it's a simple wrapper round it, if you look at the code), the main difference is that it has an additional `...` argument, that @Onyambu uses here to specify `collapse=","`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can extract the values from the output of `unnest`, process a little to make your column names, and then `spread` back out. Note that I use `flatten_chr` because of your depth-one list-column, but if it is nested you can use `flatten` and `spread` works just as well on list-cols.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.1
mydf <- data_frame(
  regular_col = c(1, 2),
  normal_col = c("a", "b"),
  weird_col = list(
    list("hakuna", "matata"),
    list("squash", "banana")
  )
)
mydf %>%
  unnest(weird_col) %>%
  group_by(regular_col, normal_col) %>%
  mutate(
    weird_col = flatten_chr(weird_col),
    weird_colname = str_c("weirdo_", row_number())
    ) %>% # or just as.character
  spread(weird_colname, weird_col)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   regular_col, normal_col [2]
#>   regular_col normal_col weirdo_1 weirdo_2
#>         <dbl> <chr>      <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1           1 a          hakuna   matata  
#> 2           2 b          squash   banana
```

Created on 2018-08-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5):

`unnest` develops lists and vectors vertically, and one row data frames horizontally. So what we can do is change your lists into data frames (with adequate column names) and `unnest` afterwards.

```
mydf %>% mutate(weird_col = map(weird_col,~ as_data_frame(
  setNames(.,paste0("weirdo_",1:length(.)))
  ))) %>% 
  unnest

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   regular_col normal_col weirdo_1 weirdo_2
#         <dbl>      <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
# 1           1          a   hakuna   matata
# 2           2          b   squash   banana
```

Comment: pretty nice and concise!

Comment: It's similar to what @Onyambu suggested in the comments, except that he first transforms the list into a comma separated string, that will be spread horizontally with `separate`

Comment: would this solution work if the number of elements in the list could vary in different rows?

Comment: yes it would, try removing `'matata'` from the first list, you would get`NA` in column `weirdo_2`

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr` 1.0 introduced [`unnest_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unnest_wider.html) for exactly this purpose.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf <- data_frame(regular_col = c(1,2),
                   normal_col = c('a','b'),
                   weird_col = list(list('hakuna', 'matata'),
                                    list('squash', 'banana')))

mydf %>% unnest_wider(weird_col, names_sep = '_')
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   regular_col normal_col weird_col_1 weird_col_2
#>         <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1           1 a          hakuna      matata     
#> 2           2 b          squash      banana
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>